# Whitelist a call subset of a pallet

Tags: frame, call

Is there a way to whitelist a call subset of a pallet? And hide the rest from the end user.

```
// something like
Pallet { fn call_a(){} fn call_b(){} }; // Some Pallet
...
construct_runtime!(
    pub enum Runtime {
        .....
        Some: pallet_some::{Pallet, Call{call_a}, Storage, Event<T>} = 3
        .....
    }
);
// as a result for an end user only call_a is available
```

Comment: What are you trying to do more specifically? why do you need it?

Comment: For example: perhaps you want to have only _specific origins_ to successfully pass an ensure origin check otherwise the call fails, and although not "hidden" (or not actually included in the runtime) it could be non-functional for anyone but specific (or no) origins.

Answer (score 4):

There is no way to do this.

You can remove the entire `Call` from the runtime:

```
construct_runtime! {
   ..
   MyPallet: my_pallet exclude_parts { Call },
   ..
}
```

This will remove `Call` and will leave all other parts like `Origin`, `Event` etc as part of your runtime.

The only solution to prevent users from calling certain calls of a pallet is to use the `BaseCallFilter`:

```
pub struct TestBaseCallFilter;
impl Contains<RuntimeCall> for TestBaseCallFilter {
    fn contains(c: &RuntimeCall) -> bool {
        match *c {
            // Only allow `whatever` and `yes` calls from `MyPallet`.
            RuntimeCall::MyPallet(call) => match call {
                my_pallet::Call::whatever { .. } => true,
                my_pallet::Call::yes { .. } => true,
                _ => false,
            },
            _ => true,
        }
    }
}
```

These calls will not be "hidden" from the user, but in a "perfect world" a normal user would also use some dedicated app for your runtime. This dedicated app wouldn't provide a way to construct these "forbidden" calls.